# i want to have borders on the left, right, and top, with a border radius applied to to top left and top right in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have borders with white color on the left, right, and top, with a border radius applied to top left and top right(as the given image)[image] in flutter..! do not want to apply border on bottom(I tried with everything but..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this to have all borders except the bottom one of a container?

Here the width for the bottom border is zero and there is no border radius for the bottom corners.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomeWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const BorderSide borderSide = BorderSide(width: 4, color: Colors.white);
    const Radius radius = Radius.circular(20);
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          border: Border(
            left: borderSide,
            right: borderSide,
            top: borderSide,
            bottom: BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: radius, topRight: radius),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: SomeWidget(),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: oh god..got it..appreciate it bro..

Comment: no problem friend!